# What's the sum of the series? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}$

Tags: analysis, power-series

So, for 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ (-1)^{n+1}x^{2n+1}}{(2n-1)(2n+1)}\ ,$$

I know the answer involves $\tan^{-1}(x)$ because the series representation is there for it. But, I don't know what to do with the $\frac{-1}{2n-1}$ that's there. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, but I just can't see it. Help? Suggestions?

Comment: The term $\frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$ is a hint that it is related to differentiation.

Comment: Anyone whats the actual answerR?

Comment: @CuriousSciDude If you split up the sum using the hint you should get, $$ (x^{2} + 1)\tan^{-1}(x) - x $$ If you want to check your work you can always try wolfram aplha.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{(2n-1)(2n+1)} =\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n+1}\Big)$$

Comment: Very nice. I was about to differentiate and complicate things.